# Vote arrow not reset when attempting to undo vote on locked post

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, user-interface, locked-questions

Scenario:

1. Find a locked post that you voted on (upvote or downvote). I found one with [What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon).
2. Try to undo the vote. => The arrow will be unhighlighted, and the vote count will be *briefly* changed.
3. An error message displays "This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on." When this displays, the vote count is reset, but the arrow is not.
4. After dismissing the dialog, the vote arrow is still not reset.

Note: **this does *not* happen when attempting to remove a vote that is too old to change**, so there is already some code written which will handle this properly.

Comment: This also happens on [deleted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114101/151301).

Comment: Locked questions now no longer display the up/down voting, so it only becomes a matter of I-haven't-refreshed-it-since-it-was-locked and deleted questions/answers (same haven't-refreshed-since-it-was-deleted situation or 10k tools). It also has the effect that the UI doesn't realise that you have voted, so where it was orange -1 and you click the down arrow, it goes to plain 0 then back to plain -1 with the error, thereafter it will go to orange -2 and then back to plain -1 with the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is displayed correctly again when you refresh the page.

I'm not for or against it, but it seems to unimportant to fix unless it's adding one line of code.

Comment: yeah, it's only a display issue. but they must have similar code already written, since it works properly when trying to undo a vote that is too old