# Glitch when trying to vote on deleted answers

Tags: bug, voting, user-interface, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote arrow not reset when attempting to undo vote on locked post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44137/vote-arrow-not-reset-when-attempting-to-undo-vote-on-locked-post)

I think I found a quite unimportant bug in the SO-software. It is hard to reproduce for an ordinary user, since the initial state needed to reproduce it is rare:

1. Get 10 000 reputation points to see deleted answers of all users
2. Find a deleted answer you have (up)voted on before it got deleted. You should still see the highlighted upvote-button
3. Try to vote on that answer or to remove your previous vote. You will now see an infobox that informs you that it's impossible to vote on deleted answers.
4. The highlight on your previous (up)vote is not coming back. This is a glitch.
5. If you refresh the page, the highlight returns. The glitch only affects the frontend

Comment: Refresh the page, and it will return.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, that's true. This is why I said, that this glitch is quite unimportant.

Comment: Er. Reproducing this is kind of trivial. Vote on a post, delete it, try to unvote

Comment: @Michael Except that you need a lot of rep to delete a post that is not your own.

Comment: @FUZxxl Well, I assume you want devs to reproduce this; they can do whatever they want

Comment: @Michael well, from that point of view you are right.

Comment: `Reproducing this is kind of trivial`...yes, if you already have 10k rep ;)

Comment: @tombull89 I just went through this with FUZxxl :). I meant it's easy for devs to reproduce, which are the only people that really need to be able to reproduce a bug